# Find a substring in another column query?

Tags: sql, database, select, db2, sql-like

I need to find a substring of a string in one table but different columns like

```
TableA
+-------+------------+
| name  | school     |
+-------+------------+
| jhon  | st.jhon    |
+-------+------------+
| mary  | st.mary    |
+-------+------------+
| mike  | st.patrick |
+-------+------------+
```

I need to find a substring such as a mary in st.mary

I tried to do `select name, school from TableA where name like ('%',school,'%')` but it's not working.

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: @mustaccio i meant as, am getting an empty table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`school` contains `name`, so your `like` condition is backwards. Flip the columns and you should be OK:

```
SELECT name, school
FROM   tablea
WHERE  SCHOOL LIKE '%' || name || '%'
```